# Reflection in Ruby. Instantiate an object by given class name

Tags: ruby, reflection

I came to ruby from PHP.
How could i do the next thing in ruby?

```
$className = 'ArrayObject';
$arrayObject = new $className();
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do this:

```
arrayObject = Object::const_get('Array').new
```

Answer (score 24):

You can also use the following if you are using Ruby on Rails:

```
array_object = "Array".constantize.new
```

Comment: Looks like solution from RoR. Thank you!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `constantize` is a core extension added to Ruby by the Rails' ActiveSupport module i.e. it's not pure Ruby.

Comment: If you're working with a lowercase string/symbol, you can apply `CamelCasing` prior to constantizing, i.e. `:array.to_s.camelize.constantize.new` or `'array'.camelize.constantize.new`.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a class, like for example String:

```
a = String
a.new("Geo")
```

would give you a string. The same thing applies to other classes ( number & type of parameters will differ of course ).

Comment: While this doesn't directly answer the question, it's a good point that since classes are objects, you can store them just like any other object and this might be a better approach in many cases where you'd be tempted to use a string in another language.